# Maven - "resources:resources" goal invocation with help of "invoker" goal of iterator plugin

Tags: java, maven

I have two files in `resources` folder of my maven project. I need to just copy them without filtering. I can do it by `resources:resources` invocation or 'iterator:invoker' invocation. So I'm trying to use second variant - using iterator plugin. If I invoke 'resources:resources' it's working fine - these files are copied successfully. But if I invoke iterator:invoker, I get error:

> Failed to execute goal
>   com.soebes.maven.plugins:iterator-maven-plugin:0.3:invoker
>   (default-cli) on project Task4Maven_TwoProfiles_Invoker:
>
> Unable to
>   parse configuration of mojo
>   com.soebes.maven.plugins:iterator-maven-plugin:0.3:invoker for
>   parameter goals: Cannot assign configuration entry 'goals' with value
>   'resources:@item@' of type java.lang.String to property of type
>   java.util.List -> [Help 1]

Piece of my POM file:

```
  <build>
    <!--<pluginManagement>-->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <!--ITERATOR PLUGIN-->
            <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <items>
                        <item>resources</item>
                    </items>
                    <goals>resources:@item@</goals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    <!--</pluginManagement>-->
  </build>
```

Please, could you hint me what I do wrong?

Comment: You can do that with iterator-maven-plugin but it sounds like you are going the wrong direction. Can you show your full pom file and best would be having a full example project.

Comment: I placed the project here: https://github.com/dmalygin/Task4Maven_Invoker.git

Comment: Also there's one interesting task - invocation of two profiles (assembly:single -Pprofile1 and assembly:single -Pprofile2) with help of iterator:invoker goal. It doesn't work too. I placed it here: https://github.com/dmalygin/Task4Maven_TwoProfiles_Invoker.git

Comment: khmarbaise,let me ask you, had you chance to check my project? I mean 'Task4Maven_Invoker'